# How to add JavaScript control (JavaScript package) downloaded from GitHub in my asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, npm

I am new to GitHub so asking very basic questions.
I downloaded https://github.com/jspreadsheet/ce  package (.zip) file  to use in my asp.net web application. I don't know how to add these files in my application. When I unzip the folder i have got differnt directries and files. Not sure how to use these filse in my application. I have created simple new asp.net webform appliation. Please suggest how can I add this control in my application. Thank you.

[image: unziped folder structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the following steps to use javascript files and css files in the asp.net webform app.

**First**, please create two folders(Css,Javascript) in your web app.

**Second**, you can add all the css files and js files to the correspond folders from the downloaded file.

[image]

**Third**, you can write the following code to reference the files.

```
<script src="Javascript/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
```

Besides, since I can not find jsuites related file, I used online reference.

**Finally**, you can use the following code to create an online sheet.

```
<body>
    <div>The following is table</div>
   <div id="spreadsheet"></div>
</body>
<script>
        var data = [
            ['Jazz', 'Honda', '2019-02-12', '', true, '$ 2.000,00', '#777700'],
            ['Civic', 'Honda', '2018-07-11', '', true, '$ 4.000,01', '#007777'],
        ];

        jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
            data: data,
            columns: [
                { type: 'text', title: 'Car', width: 120 },
                { type: 'dropdown', title: 'Make', width: 200, source: ["Alfa Romeo", "Audi", "Bmw"] },
                { type: 'calendar', title: 'Available', width: 200 },
                { type: 'image', title: 'Photo', width: 120 },
                { type: 'checkbox', title: 'Stock', width: 80 },
                { type: 'numeric', title: 'Price', width: 100, mask: '$ #.##,00', decimal: ',' },
                { type: 'color', width: 100, render: 'square', }
            ]
        });
</script>
```

**Final result**:

[image]